# Translating page and contact form using JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a  tag that gives my users the option to view the page in either English or Bulgarian:

```
<select id="LangSelect" class="select">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="bg">Български</option>
</select>
```

And the page gets translated here is my JS code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fade').fadeToggle(1000).fadeToggle(1000);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cookieLanguage = $.cookie('language');
        if (cookieLanguage && ['bg', 'en'].indexOf(cookieLanguage) > -1)
            $('html').attr('lang', cookieLanguage);

        $('#LangSelect').change(function () {
            var lang = $(this).val();
            $('html').attr('lang', lang);
            $.cookie('language', lang, {
                expires: 7
            });
        }); 
    });
```

And my CSS code that hides the other language parts:

```
[lang="bg"] .lang-en {
    display: none;
}

[lang="en"] .lang-bg {
    display: none;
```

Next I have my contact form:

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
      <div id="contact"></div>
      <div id="flip" class="f-btn lang-en"><span>Contact Me &raquo;</span></div>
      <div id="flip" class="f-btn lang-bg"><span>Свържи се с мен &raquo;</span></div>

      <ul id="foot-social">
          <li>

          </li>
          <li>

          </li>
          <li>

          </li>
          <li>

          </li>
          <li>

          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="" class="codepen" title="CodePen">

              </a>
          </li>

      </ul>
      <br>
      <div id="panel" class="lang-bg">
          <p class="lang-en">Please contact me for any questions, comments or inquiries.</p>
          <p class="lang-bg">Чрез тази форма може да се свържете с мен.</p>
          <div class="con-form">
              <form action="" id="form" method="post" name="form">
                  <input class="lang-en" name="client" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" value="" required pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" title="firstname lastname">
                  <input class="lang-bg" name="client" placeholder="Вашето Име" type="text" value="" required pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" title="firstname lastname">

                  <input class="lang-en" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" type="email" value="" required>
                  <input class="lang-bg" name="email" placeholder="Вашия Имейл" type="email" value="" required>
                  <textarea class="lang-en" name="comment" placeholder="Your Comments Here..." id="comment"></textarea>
                  <textarea class="lang-bg" name="comment" placeholder="Съобщение..." id="comment"></textarea>
                  <input class="o-btn lang-en" type="Submit" value="Submit">
                  <input class="o-btn lang-bg" type="Submit" value="Изпрати">

              </form>

          </div>

      </div>

      <a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
      <div class="footer-images">

         <img class="social" src="images/twitter.png">
      </div>
  </footer>
```

That gets powered by this JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
         $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 10000
    });
    });
});
```

When the user chooses either English or Bulgarian from the select menu the page gets translated and well as the contact form works in English perfectly fine, but when you translate the page to Bulgarian and you click on the contact button the form does not display at all, this problem has been bugging me for a couple of days now and I can't put my finger on it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(function () {` and `$(document).ready(function () {`are exactly the same thing. You should only have one of these, because the document gets ready only once per loading. Besides, you have multiple ids. ID stands for Unique IDentifier, so you can't have twice the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 10000
        });
    });
});
```

New Code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 10000
        });
    });
});
```

Every time you change languages `$("#panel").slideToggle();` is called. This means that every time you change language the panel will switch from setting the height to 0 and setting the height to initial (or whatever height you originally set it to). So it takes two clicks to hide the element and show it again.
Here is the JQuery API for .slideToggle: https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

You also have `panel` as an id instead of a class which may be part of the problem. 
(Just as a note, you can get rid of `$(document).ready(function () {` in the code used for translating since you already have `$(function () {` at the top)

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out my mistakes, I wrote a new function with classes for the Bulgarian part and it worked